# Is this function strongly concave?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

Is the mapping $X\in E\mapsto \textsf{Tr}(X^{1/2})$ strongly concave, where $E$ is the set of all real symmetric, positive definite matrices (of fixed size) with eigenvalues between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, for some given $0<\alpha\leq \beta$ (if so, what is the strong concavity parameter, as a function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?)